# Embed image into xls sheet via python

Tags: python, excel, export-to-excel

Currently I have a data export going on that does a CSV file like:

```
name, file
foo, http://www.google.com/favicon.ico
```

But now I need to make something that embeds the image in a way that it would be visible in excel. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

[xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) is a nice package for creating `.xls` files. And as these examples ([1](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/examples/image.py), [2](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/examples/image_chg_col_wid.py)) suggest, it can embed images. Though it can only embed `Windows Bitmap` format, namely `.bmp` files. If you have images in a different format, you may need to process them first.